# Dividing line in horizontal menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I have this menu -

```
<div ><ul id="menu">
        <li class="one"><a href="http://www.domain.com">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="two"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="three"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>messages">Messages</a></li>
        <li class="four"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>friends">Friends</a></li>
        <li><?php bp_adminbar_notifications_menu() ?>
        <ul>
        <li> </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Is there anyway I can add vertical dividing lines between the items?
Thanks

Comment: There are different option. You can use some graphic when it should look kind of fancy, or you can also use a simple border on the li's

Comment: How would add an image between the items?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `:after` to place them:

```
#menu > li:after {
  content: '|' /* or url('divider.png'); */
}
#menu > li:last-child:after {
  content: none;
}
```

I suspect this may be what you're after. Though note that your browser support will be somewhat limited to more modern browsers. Fortunately the degrading is very graceful and won't break on older browsers.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/awarih/edit#html,live
Demo (with image): http://jsbin.com/awarih/2/edit#html,live

Comment: Take not that for cross browser compatibility, the :after and :last-child is a fairly new selector!

Comment: @Zuul Works in both IE8 and IE9, which is good enough for many people. Of course when you get to IE7 you lose even some of the positioning options with `display`, so separate considerations need to be made there.

Comment: How would I add an image in between the menu items?

Comment: Starting from the Jonathan's answer, you would li:after{content:url(nice_pipe.jpg);}

Comment: Using a background-image would be simpler than using :after, and more appropriate.

Comment: can i do this without image? like li:after{content:"<span class='divider'></span>" and span.divider{height:100%;  width:1px;background:white} or it could be error prone ??